# How to make "rename -n ..." output to a file?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, rename

I'm experimenting with some arguments for the `rename` command by using `-n` option to do "dry runs". How to make it output into a file so I can analyze more? The following does not work -- the resultant rename.log is empty:

```
bash$ echo "XXX" > \"XXX\"__XXX.txt

$ rename -n 's/"([^\/"《》]+)"__(.*)/“$1”__$2/' '{}' \; *.txt > rename.log
'"XXX"__XXX.txt' would be renamed to '“XXX”__XXX.txt'
```

Comment: Try adding `2>&1` at the right end in case it is writing on `stderr`.

Comment: Is that really a funny quotes? `“$1”` (unicode, i think) or just a typo?

Comment: @Jetchisel that's called [smart quotes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_quotes)

Comment: @phuclv thanks for pointing that out. I just don't think it will be smart enough when you use it in scripting, yes?

Comment: @Jetchisel it's quite useful in writing so any decent word processor will emit smart quotes. However some OSes like macOS also actively produce smart quotes when you type scripts normally or even copy-paste scripts from the browsers, which is a pain in the \*\*\*

Comment: @phuclv, ok, good to know. thanks for the info. pain in the `eye` :P

Answer (score 0):

Mark's comment is correct, it seems the `-n` option outputs on `stderr`. So you can run a command like this:

```
rename -n [options] > rename.log 2>&1
```

If you wanted to pipe the output to another command (as I was trying to do), put the redirection before the pipe:

```
rename -n [options] 2>&1 | less
```